# How do I update a value of a variable in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**Context:**

I am working in MemberMouse (a WordPress Membership Plugin), and I am trying to write a script that updates a member's status to "Cancelled" after a Refund has been issued on their account.

I've been provided with a sample script that simply pulls/provides the users information: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/265387542/files/payment_notification_script.php

**Problem:** 
I want to take `$status = $_GET["status"];` and update it to "Cancelled". How can I achieve this? Is there a way to `$_POST` a status value back to MemberMouse, or to set `$status` equal to something else?

(I am a novice with PHP). Here's my attempt below:
...

```
// ---- PERFORM ACTION BASED ON EVENT TYPE ----
switch($eventType)
{       
    case $REFUND_ISSUED:
        // set status to cancel
        mm_member_status_change("Cancelled");

        break;
}
```

Comment: As a simple debug process, try to put Javascript alert in the $REFUND_ISSUED to see if you are landing in this script or not. If yes, which is the alert shows, then there is nothing wrong in the process. It is the value change code that needs to be fixed. In this case, please share your code from where you are referring mm_member_status_change to.

Comment: I put a `mail()` function in $REFUND_ISSUED and it worked fine, that is the email was sent to me successfully.

Comment: As for the code I got `mm_member_status_chage`, it's from another template MemberMouse provides:

// ---- EVENT TYPES ----
$MEMBER_MEMBERSHIP_CHANGE = "mm_member_membership_change";

Comment: Without seeing the full code, it will be difficult to pinpoint the error. What I can suggest as of now is to try to change the value of mm_member_status_chage with a simple code with only one line to change the value. It appears that you are not referring to the required class properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you are new to PHP, here are some points you may not know.
1.  $status = $_GET["status"]; may not be doing what you think it is doing.

this line is saying two things.

1. it is declaring a variable $status
2. it is setting that
       variable to the URL variable $_GET["status"];

What is a URL variable?
in this case, it would look something like this in the URL.

> www.mysitename.com/index.php?**status=canceled**

so, if you want to change the "status", you simply redefine the variable like so.

```
$status="canceled";
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I didn't realize it was being treated as a URL variable. Essentially, I just wrote a script that calls the API URL, appending the variables needed to update the member's account status. Worked perfectly. THANK YOU!